# Triggered escalations from cosmic signatures

Tags: eve-online

When you have an exploration DED complex site escalation listed in your mission journal, is it possible for another party to discover that same escalation and beat you to the rewards, or are you free to pursue it at your leisure until the timer expires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The escalation site doesn't appear in the game until you warp to it. Once you've landed on the site your ship can be be probed down by other players, who can then race you to the reward. Until then however the escalation is safe.